# Can two USB3 5Gbps peripherals use full 10Gbps bandwidth of USB 3.2 (Gen2x1) hub?

Tags: usb, usb-device

I have two USB3 Vision cameras, which are 5Gbps USB3.0 peripherals. They are connected to Nvidia Jetson Orin, which has only a single USB3 bus implemented by an internal USB 3.2 (Gen2x1) hub. Is it possible for two 5Gbps USB3.0 peripherals to use separate lanes of Gen2x1 hub, so they don't have to share the bandwidth of a single 5Gbps lane?

---

Here is more info:

```
nick@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1ab2:0001  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0420 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1ab2:0001 Allied Vision ALVIUM 1800 U-052m
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2516:0004 Cooler Master Co., Ltd. Storm QuickFire Rapid Mechanical Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 045e:0040 Microsoft Corp. Wheel Mouse Optical
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5420 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:3549 IMC Networks Bluetooth Radio
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
nick@ubuntu:~$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=tegra-xusb/4p, 10000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=, 5000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=, 5000M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 10000M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=, 5000M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=tegra-xusb/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=rtk_btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=rtk_btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
```

The cameras have `1ab2:0001` IDs. For some reason, the manufacturer is listed only for one of them. Not sure how to read this tree regarding the bandwidth sharing.

---

Both cameras in type-A ports:

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=tegra-xusb/4p, 10000M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 10000M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=, 5000M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=, 5000M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=, 5000M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Miscellaneous Device, Driver=, 5000M
```

This suggests a possibility of each camera getting its own 5Gbps lane from 10Gbps hub, even though they share the bus 02.

Compare this with a mini-PC where each camera is on a separate bus, removing all doubts of bandwidth sharing at USB level:

```
Bus 009 Device 002: ID 1ab2:0001 Allied Vision Vision device
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 1ab2:0001 Allied Vision Vision device
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

Comment: Per its datasheet, NVIDIA Jetson Orin Nano, this device has USB3.2 host controller with 3 individual ports. Could you please be a little bit more specific about the model you are using?

Comment: @Ale..chenski I'm using Jetson AGX Orin Developer Kit, but the target will be Orin Nano. My question is not about ports, it is about not sharing 5Gbps bandwidth between 2 peripherals.

Comment: These SFF modules all have multiple USB3.2 Gen2x1 ports. The "reference carrier boards" also have multiple Gen2 ports. Where your concern is coming from? Which 5Gbps to share? Which "internal hub" you are talking about? Could you just make a picture of your proposed USB tree - host->root_ports->devices?

Comment: @Ale..chenski When I plug 2 USB3 cameras to any combination of 2 out of 3 USB3 ports on Jetson AGX Orin Developer Kit, *lsusb* shows them being on the same bus. I'm assuming it means they are sharing the same 5Gbps bandwidth.

Comment: Your assumption is obviously wrong. The front-end of USB controller sits on a single bus (AXI or PCIe), it is true. Why do you assume that it is limited to 5Gbps? But the controller does have at least three Gen2 ports. Usually the front-side bus bandwidth of a controller matches the aggregate port bandwidth. Even if it is not so, the bandwidth should be no less than a single Gen2 port, or  equivalent to 10Gsps. Therefore two cams on different ports should have no issues at all.

Comment: You can check your aggregate bandwidth by connecting two high-end mass storage devices (USB-to-NVMe), and run the standard Linux performance tool simultaneously on both drives. And why don't you simply post the output of lsusb -t here, for clarity?

Comment: @Ale..chenski I added more info. Sorry for the delay, but I didn't have convenient access to Jetson earlier.

Comment: Yep, I never was able to fully comprehend the cryptic graph of lsusb -t. Maybe more coherent info can be found if using this tool, https://superuser.com/q/1180854/620011   Anyway, your concern is still unfounded, you should have both cams to be served with no problem, unless there is comething else like lack of driver support for concurrent INs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From NVIDIA document Jetson_AGX_Orin_Series_Data_Sheet_DS-10662-001_v1.5.pdf

5.1 USB Interfaces

The NVIDIA Jetson AGX Orin SOM provides 4x USB 2.0 and 3x USB3.2 Gen2 x1 port for communication to external peripheral devices. In host mode, the USB3.2 host controller supports up to Gen2 Super Speed+, 10 Gbps. In device mode, the USB3.2 controller supports up to Gen1 Super Speed.

**Note: There are two hubs internal for USB 3.2, and each has 10Gbps bandwidth. One hub is for ports 0/1 and the other for ports 2/3.**

USB interfaces are compliant with the following USB specifications:

 Universal Serial Bus Specification Revision 3.2 Gen 1 and 2

. . .

Elaboration: host USB controller has downstream ports that transmit data in a serial way, measured roughly in Gbits per seconds. The upstream interface to system fabric/memory is, however, a wide parallel interface, 32/64 or more bits wide. The upstream interface usually is designed to provide a bandwidth to satisfy all downstream ports, it is fairly easy with wide parallel buses like PCIe or AXI.

Even if the cams (5Gbps) are connected to the same internal hub (10Gbps), USB 3.2 specification require the hubs to translate the 10Gbps traffic into two separate 5Gbps streams for downstream ports, so any variant of cams connection should provide full 5Gbps service to them.

The second example with miniPC indicates that the user ports are driven by two separate USB controllers, which is just more costly to implement.

I should be noted, however, that the Jetson documentation is inconsistent. The top-level block diagram does not show any embedded hubs, only a single 3.2 three-port controller:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. *USB 3.2 specification require the hubs to translate the 10Gbps traffic into two separate 5Gbps streams* was the information I was looking for.